# Understanding styled components component selector and ampersand

Tags: javascript, html, css, styled-components

In styled-components docs, they have this example:

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components

[image]

It shows an Icon that changes color when you hover its parent, which is a link, in this case.

```
const Link = styled.a`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: papayawhip;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

const Icon = styled.svg`
  flex: none;
  transition: fill 0.25s;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;

  ${Link}:hover & {         // <---- This is what I'm not understanding
    fill: rebeccapurple;
  }
`;
```

From the Docs, we know that:

> **Doc Note #1:** styled-components solves this use case cleanly via the "component
>   selector" pattern. Whenever a component is created or wrapped by the
>   styled() factory function, it is also assigned a stable CSS class for
>   use in targeting.

And also that:

> **Doc Note #2:** Ampersands (&) get replaced by our generated, unique classname for
>   that styled component, making it easy to have complex logic.

---

Let's analyze `${Link}:hover &`

I know it gets translated into the browser as:

[image]

and:

[image]

I understand that `sc-kAzzGY` is the "stable CSS class" (Doc Note #1) that is created whenever an element is wrapped by the `styled` function.

I also know that the Ampersand (&) gets replaced by their generated unique classname (Doc Note #2) for that styled components. Hence, `kDmLky` is that class.

**QUESTION**

But what does the resulting selector (picture below) is actually selecting? Can anybody explain that to me?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${Link}` is pointing to `const Link` i.e.: "Hovering my parent changes my style" which gets a class of `sc-kAzzGY`.

`&` is kinda like saying "**And** add this to the current class(es)/id(s)/etc." 
So,

```
.my-class {
 some-css: awesomeness;
 &:hover {
   more-css: extra-cool;
 }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
.my-class {
 some-css: awesomeness;
}
.my-class:hover {
   more-css: extra-cool;
}
```

Therefore, `&` points to the containing element `const Icon` i.e. the speech bubble and gets a class of `kDmLky`.

When `Link` is hovered, cause `Icon` to have `fill: rebeccapurple`

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify things a bit more:

When you have a declaration block inside of another declaration block like the example below, that inner declaration block becomes an independent one.

```
const Icon = styled.svg`
  flex: none;
  transition: fill 0.25s;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;

  ${Link}:hover & {       // This declaraition block becomes an independent one
    fill: rebeccapurple;
  }
`;
```

And the result, in this case, is a declaration block with a selection that says:

When you have a class `&` which is descendent of the class `${Link}` which is in the `hover` state, apply these rules:

`fill: rebeccapurple;`

**NOTE:** `${Link}` refers to the Link class and `&` refers to the Icon class (svg).

Answer (score 3):

```
${Link}:hover &
```

Here the ampersand & is the short hand way for referring to the top level component being defined, so I would read it as

```
${Link}:hover ${Icon}
```

i.e. it is referring to an Icon component contained inside of a Link component being hovered over

I would also recommend [this link](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled) to see the more general use case for component selectors with styled components, where it's used in a parent child configuration for selection, and applied to the child